# Why does a new G Suite user has access to all GCP resources by default and how to restrict this access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-iam

I have G Suite account, say example.com and I add a new user called user1@example.com. Now this user logs into GCP (Google Cloud Platform) console and he has access to all resources under example.com organization. No roles have been assigned to this user using Cloud IAM and no specific policies are defined.

It is expected that user1@example.com by default doesn't have any access to resources under GCP till some role is assigned

Comment: Do you have groups with roles assigned?

Comment: I have groups with roles assigned but this user is not part of any group

Comment: When you create a new user in G Suite (new email address) they have ZERO permissions in GCP until you add that user to GCP IAM. Double-check the IAM member listing for this user and see what permissions they have. You can also look in the Stackdriver Audit logs to see when/how permissions were granted.

Comment: That's exactly what I was expecting. But that user can log into GCP console and access resources. I don't see anything under IAM for this user. However there is a user of type "Domain" called <example.com> under IAM who has 'owner' permission on that domain.

Comment: Google Cloud IAM supports the member type `domain`. All email addresses in that domain inherit the permissions of the domain member. The domain member is similar to a group member.

Comment: The IAM `Project Owner` role should only be assigned to an executive in the company. I would never assign this permission to an entire domain. You have a security problem. Fix it as Project Owners can do anything they want to the project including removing everyone else so that only that person has full control.

Comment: Thanks  @JohnHanley . Modifying permission of this [tag:domain] user did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this question, the problem is caused by having the Cloud IAM member type "domain:" added as a member assigned with Project Owner role. Everyone in the same domain inherits the permissions assigned to the domain member.

For clarity, you have the domain name `example.com`. If you add the IAM member `domain:example.com` to Cloud IAM, everyone that has an email address, eg `someone@example.com` will inherit the permissions assigned to `domain:example.com` automatically.

The domain member requires that the email addresses are managed by either G Suite or Cloud Identity.

[G Suite Domain](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#g_suite_domain)